# Question regarding function calls within for loops

Tags: c, cs50

I am writing a simple code that runs a plurality vote. My code seems to work only if I don't call the bool vote function after `char *name = get_string("Vote: ")` Why is this the case? The logic that I don't understand is that char *name changes every time a new value is assigned with get_string n number times in the for loop. If this is the case, shouldn't it logically make sense to call the vote function for each name before a new value is assigned to name? Why doesn't the code work after I add a line that calls the vote function before each iteration of the for loop?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct candidate
{
    char *name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;
int voter_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(char *name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        char *name = get_string("Vote: ");
        //The main difference between the answer and my code was that I tried to call vote(name) at this point. I should figue out why this is incorrect, and the following logical explanation.

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(char *name)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    int maxVotes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > maxVotes)
        {
            maxVotes = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == maxVotes)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mre]. (a) You seem to have posted code that is working but only described the code that is not working. It is describe as “a call to vote(name),” but the exact code is not shown. Show the **exact** code that fails. And, since there is also working code, show the **exact** working code. (b) You do not describe the way in which the code fails. Show the **exact** input for a failing case, show the **exact** program output (or behavior) in the failing case, and show the **exact** program output that would be expected from a working program. State what the difference is.

Comment: The could be optimized for clarity at some points, but it seems to work. Where you say in the comment that you wanted to call vote(), two lines later you do (in the if construct). What exactly is your problem? It is not easy to understand for other people. Please explain it to us ;-)

Comment: Post sample command line arguments and input used.  Problem may lurk there.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that the spec says "*You should not modify anything else in plurality.c*", there already *is* a call to `vote(name)` for each voter here `if (!vote(name))`.

It does not "*logically make sense to call the vote function for each name before a new value is assigned to name*" because the order of operations is:

- get a candidate name for voter i
- add that vote to the selected candidate